# How to convert object of one class into object of another class with same attributes in Java

Tags: java

I have a class A with variables x and y and I have a class B with same variables x and y, I have created object for A and initialized values for x and y, now I need have object of class B with same value of initialized variables x and y like I have to cast of convert that object of A.

```
Class A{
      int x;
      int y;
}

Class B{
      int x;
      int y;
}
```

I will import Class A and B to the class Sample

```
Class Sample{
      A a = null;
      B b = null;
      public static void main(String args[]){
         a = new A();
         a.x = 5;
         a.y = 6;
         b = (B) a;
         System.out.println("x = "+b.x); #it should be 5
}
```

Like this I want, how to cast object of class A to object of B or how to do like this

Comment: Java does not support "structural casting" like this. Either make `B` extend `A`, or implement a factory method copying the `A` state to a new `B` object.

Comment: Oh ok, in any way I can set those variables of Class A to Class B in easier way other than  using setter and getter methods @fluffy

Comment: I forgot to mention the `B` constructor copying the `A` class state too (however, I never do like that). So you have at least three ways of doing so: 1) using a parameter tuple-to-fields constructor `B(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }`; 2) using a copying constructor like `B(A a) { this(a.x, a.y); }` (considering you have both constructors); 3) using a factory method (possibly declared in the `B` class): `static B from(A a) { return new B(a.x, a.y); }` (I prefer the latter). I any case, Java does not work like C/C++ (where layout matters) or JavaScript (where names matter).

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try it out

Comment: There are libraries like Apache Commons BeanUtils or Spring BeanUtils offering methods `copyProperties`: [ApacheCommons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) or [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) but they use reflection which may be an overkill.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Can you give me with sample example code using that functionalities

Comment: Runtime reflection-based state copying is quite inefficient and it is designed from quite different things. Compile-time copying is much better in very most cases despite you either use manually written copy methods/constructors, or use compile-time mappers like MapStruct.